# aria-haspopup="true" not working, page still navigates to link on touchscreen

Tags: css, touch-event

I have a dropdown menu. On non-touch screen devices the dropdown menu is shown on hover.

On touch screen the menu is shown on click until the page navigates away. The user clicks the dropdown show but the page still navigates away. I have added aria-haspopup which I thought would prevent the page from navigating away on the first touch of the element. But the user is still navigated to the page.

```
<span class="navbar-dropdown">                                                  
  <a href="/page" aria-haspopup="true"><span>page</span></a>
  <a>etc</a>
</span>
```

How can I stop the link from navigating away on the first link Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `aria-` attributes are used to describe the behaviour of your element to assistive technologies such as screen readers. They don't alter the normal behaviour of the elements in a regular browser.

[ARIA - Accessibility | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA)

If you want to prevent the browser from following the link, you will need to use Javascript instead.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying, this microsoft article says it can be used to simulate first click to act as hover on touch devices.

Comment: I'd be more inclined to trust MDN than Microsoft for web standards documentation. :) But either way, you seem to have forgotten the link to the article in question.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/dev-guides/jj152135(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: That article only applies to Internet Explorer 10, and only if it's not running on Windows 7. That behaviour was never adopted by any modern browser.

Comment: So is there a standard way to do it on modern browsers? Prevent dropdown link from clicking through and instead behave as hover? Thanks

Comment: Yes - use Javascript. Handle the click event, and [prevent the default behaviour](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault).